# How to calculate X and Y coordinates of screen on different resolution?

Tags: screen, resolution

I am developing a web application to show documents (word or PDF) in a container. On top of the document I am putting transparent layer. On this layer I should be able to highlight the content and annotate using stick notes. I am saving the position of highlights and annotations using screen's X and Y coordinates. When opening the application in another screen resolution, highlights and annotations are displayed in different locations. It is obvious.

Here is my question, is there a way I can have X and Y screen coordinates of one resolution and on loading the application in different resolution, I should be able to calculate X and Y positions dynamically for that target resolution and show my highlights and annotations properly?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Regards
Jana.

Comment: Damn nobody answered this one?